# Get all users from database based on Two variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, request

I am actually working on a project where I want to get the all users from users table from multiple countries for example Mexico and UK.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE Country = 'Mexico' OR 'UK';
```

The problem with this query is it only give the users from Mexico but not for the both. The condition becomes True when I finds the result for Mexico and just pass to the next line instead of searching for users from UK too.

I hope it made sense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute this if you want it to be case sensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Country = 'Mexico' OR Country='UK';
```

OR if your data has capital as well as small cases and if some junk data in between then you might need this query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Country ILIKE '%Mexico%' OR Country ILIKE '%UK%';
```

This will basically return all results containing Mexico or UK anywhere in the data

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Country = 'Mexico' OR Country='UK';
```

Comment: Alternative you can also try using  IN... so something like this 
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Country in ('Mexico','UK)';
in case you multiple cases